# How to retrieve site url's efficiently for all users in a tenant using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Here is the problem:

I have a tenant with 50,000 users Every day I need to pull that user list to see what has changed. Example: Which users were added or removed, and what are their `mySite` URL is.

I can get some general information calling `/users` but, I need each user's `mySite`.   The only way I have found to retrieve that is to call `/users/userId?$select=mySite`.

This implies I must make 50k calls and I then encounter throttling issues.

Is there a way through Microsoft Graph (or some other mechanism) to pull the user data, including `mySite` efficiently?

Comment: Have you looked at [delta queries](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview) ?

Comment: @astaykov  Same problem with delta queries:   `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$select=displayName,givenName,surname,mySite`  yields:   `{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid Request: $select is not supported for these properties.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "6fc3cb8b-f2dd-4f5c-84b4-62dba726067f",
            "date": "2018-06-19T17:59:31"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: You cant select deep properties. Have you tried with $expand to get the mysite ?

Comment: @astaykov You can't use expand across services - I just ran across this.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191292/usersexpand-drive-fails-with-internalservererror      This is one of the gotchas with using the MS API calls right now.   The throttling is essentially terrible during business hours, but there we are very limited by the api calls such that we have to make a plethora of calls.